# ISCSI Ubuntu different Portal shows different content

Tags: ubuntu, iscsi

We use an ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server as ISCSI Target, this server used three network interface cards, each is configured for a different workloads and is configured in different network.
One nic is for internal traffic, the second is for drbd replication and the third on is for extern (public).

Unfortunatly the clients which consume the iscsi target server, wasnt correct configured and connect to the iscsi target server via the public interface.

If we now change in the connect-statement the portal for the internal iface with the same iqn, we see old contents inside the mountpoint. We only usw an img-file on the target-server as the lun.

if i discover from a client i get the result:

```
1.1.1.1:3260,1 iqn.2020-12.de.domain.iscsi:www
172.16.0.13:3260,1 iqn.2020-12.de.domain.iscsi:www
192.168.0.13:3260,1 iqn.2020-12.de.domain.iscsi:www
```

(IP Adresses changed for post)

the current login-statement is:

```
iscsiadm -m node --targetname "iqn.2020-12.de.domain.iscsi:www" --portal "1.1.1.1:3260" --login
```

with this, all is working fine and all folders we except to be there are inplace.

If we now try to connect via the internal portal with:

```
iscsiadm -m node --targetname "iqn.2020-12.de.domain.iscsi:www" --portal "172.16.0.13:3260" --login
```

some folders are missing.
We use OCFS2 for concurrent access, this as a side note

thanks for your time

Comment: i found the solution, ensure that all sessions to the target are eleminated. To accomplish this, we need to use the parameter `-u` instead of --logout (dont know why). Example command: `iscsiadm -m node --portal "1.1.1.1:3260" -u` after this, verify that there are no more sessions to the target. Type `iscsiadm -m session -P 3` if the client still has sessions, repeat the logout command with the given portal. Now you can connect to the specified (in our case internal) portal and all is fine.